# dynamic memory allocation using new with binary search in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

I am trying to find the maximum memory allocated using new[]. I have used binary search to make allocation a bit faster, in order to find the final memory that can be allocated

```
bool allocated = false;
int* ptr= nullptr;
int low = 0,high =  std::numeric_limits<int>;
while(true)
{
    try
    {
      mid = (low + high) / 2;
        ptr = new int[mid];
        delete[] ptr;
        allocated = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {....}
     if (allocated == true)
    {
        low = mid;
    }else
    {
        high = low;
        cout << "maximum memory allocated at: " << ptr << endl;
    }
}
```

I have modified my code, I am using a new logic to solve this. My problem right now is it is going to a never ending loop. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Did you mean `++alloc;`?
`

Comment: Also `value = new char[alloc];`

Comment: Depending on your OS and hardware, you may never get an exception with this method until `alloc` overflows.

Comment: Depending on your OS, the memory may not actually be allocated into physical ram until you access the elements. So put a memset in there too.

Answer (score 1):

This code is useless for a couple of reasons.

1. Depending on your OS, the memory may or may not be allocated until it is actually accessed. That is, `new` happily returns a new memory address, but it doesn't make the memory available just yet. It is actually allocated later when and if a corresponding address is accessed. Google up "lazy allocation". If the out-of-memory condition is detected at use time rather than at allocation time, allocation itself may never throw an exception.
2. If you have a machine with more than 2 gigabytes available, and your `int` is 32 bits, `alloc` will eventually overflow and become negative before the memory is exhausted. *Then* you may get a bad_alloc. Use `size_t` for all things that are sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing ++alloc and not ++allocation, it shouldn't matter what address it uses.  if you want it to use a different address every time then don't delete the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a particularly bad test.

For the first part you have *undefined behaviour*. That's because you should only ever `delete[]` the pointer returned to you by `new[]`. You need to `delete[] pvalue`, not `value`.

The second thing is that your approach will be defragmenting your memory as you're continuously allocating and deallocating contiguous memory blocks. I imagine that your program will understate the maximum block size due to this fragmentation effect. One solution to this would be to launch instances of your program as a new process from the command line, setting the allocation block size as a parameter. Use a *divide and conquer* bisection approach to attain the maximum size (with some reliability) in log(n) trials.

Comment: yes but one could argue that fragmentation is part of a normal payload. Also, fragmentation actually helps to max-out the usable space. if you have bits of memory available a bit everywhere, allocating multiple little blocks may fit in those holes, a huge block won't.